# What is the algorithm that a compiler would use while casting signed variables to larger variable types, C language?

Tags: c, casting

The answer might be compiler dependent but;

What is the expected output of the lines below?

```
signed char a = -5;
printf("%x \n", (signed short) a); 
printf("%x \n", (unsigned short) a);
```

Would a compiler fill the Most Significant Bits with zeros (0) or ones (1) while casting `signed char` to a larger variable? How and when?

---

P.S. There are other issues too. I tried to run the code below on an online compiler for testing. The outputs were not as I expected. So I added the verbose castings, but it did not work. Why is the output of `printf("%x \n", (signed char)b);` 4 bytes long instead of 1?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char a = (unsigned char)5;
    signed char b = (signed char)-5;
    
    unsigned short c;
    signed short d;
    
    c = (unsigned short)b;
    d = (signed short)b;
    
    printf("%x ||| %x ||| %x ||| %x\n", (unsigned char)a, (signed char)b, c, d);
    printf("%d ||| %d ||| %d ||| %d\n", a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d ||| %d ||| %d ||| %d\n", a, b, (signed char)c, (signed char)d);

    return 0;
}


Output:

5 ||| fffffffb ||| fffb ||| fffffffb
5 ||| -5 ||| 65531 ||| -5   
5 ||| -5 ||| -5 ||| -5
```

Comment: In those examples, the values passed to the variadic function `printf` will be implicity cast *again* to `int`, which can hold the entire range of `signed` and `unsigned`  `char` and `short` values.

Comment: @rici Is it a bit more clear now ?

Comment: How is hexadecimal `5` different from decimal `5`? As for the m.s. bits, in two's complement a negative value will have them set. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh. I mixed it with binary representation. Thank you. Something like 0x05 would make it more obvious anyway.

Comment: @xfce4 : if you want to see 0x05 (which probably *is* clearer), use the format `0x%02x`. `%x`, like `%d`, produces the minimal length string with no leading 0s (unless the number is 0). If you want something formatted differently, `printf` gives you the tool: format strings are pretty flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversions between integer types are value preserving when the value being converted is representable in the destination type.  `signed short` can represent all values representable by `signed char`, so this ...

```
signed char a = -5;
printf("%hd\n", (signed short) a);
```

... would be expected to output a line containing "-5".

Your code, however, has undefined behavior.  The conversion specifier `%x` requires the corresponding argument to have type `unsigned int`, whereas you are passing a `signed short` (converted to `int` according to the default argument promotions).

Provided that your implementation uses two's complement representation for signed integers (and I feel safe in asserting that it does), the representation will have sign-extended the original `signed char` to the width of a `signed short`, and then sign-extended *that* to the width of a (signed) `int`.  Thus, one reasonably likely manifestation of the UB in your ...

> ```
> printf("%x \n", (signed short) a);
> ```

... would be to print

> fffffffb

The other case is a bit different.  Integer conversions where the target type is unsigned and cannot represent the source value are well defined.  The source value is converted to the destination type by reducing it modulo the number of representable values in the target type.  Thus, if your `unsigned short` has 16 value bits then the result of converting -5 to `unsigned short` is -5 modulo 65536, which is 65531.

Thus,

```
printf("%hu\n", (unsigned short) a);
```

would be expected to print a line containing "65531".

Again, the `%x` conversion specifier does not match the type of the corresponding argument (`(unsigned short) a`, converted to `int` via the default argument promotions), so your `printf` has undefined behavior.  However, the conversion of a 16-bit `unsigned short` to a 32-bit `int` on a two's complement system will invole zero-extending the representation of the source, so one reasonably likely manifestation of the UB in your ...

> ```
> printf("%x \n", (unsigned short) a);
> ```

... would be to print

> fffb

.

Comment: Thank you. What confused me is that as -5 in modulo 2^16 is 65531, which is actually 2's complement of 5. So I thought %x was printing the memory content directly (according to type size in bytes). It does not seem to be a difficult task to read as many bytes as the variable type suggests. I wonder why `printf()` was designed in a way to cast the variables to `int` at the first place or %x is optimized for `unsigned int` only.

Comment: @Xfce4, Yes, the correspondence between two's complement representation and the results of the modular reduction in the conversion of a signed integer to an representation of the results of a signed to unsigned conversion is one of the key features of two's complement representation.  As for `printf()`, it is not directly responsible for the argument conversions -- *all* variadic arguments to all variadic functions are subject to the "default argument promotions", which have among their effects promoting both signed and unsigned `short` to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

In C, arguments to variadic functions (like `printf`) which are of lower rank than `int` are converted to `int`. (Not `unsigned int` unless the argument is unsigned and the same width as `int`).

Converting a `signed short` or `signed char` to `signed int` does not change the value. If you start with -5, you end up with -5.

But if you convert a negative signed value to an unsigned type (using an explicit cast, for example), the conversion is done modulo one more than the maximum value of the unsigned type. For example, the maximum value of an `unsigned short` is 65535 (on many implementations), so converting -5 to `unsigned short` results in -5 modulo 65536, which is 65531. (C's `%` operator does not produce mathematical modular reduction.) When that value is then implicitly converted to an `int`, it is still 65531, so that's what's printed with `%x` (`fffb`).

Note that it is technically incorrect to apply the format `%x` to a `signed int`. `%x` requires that the corresponding argument be an `unsigned int`. Currently, C does not guarantee what the result of interpreting a signed value as unsigned will be, but that will soon change. (It's not a conversion. At runtime, types no longer exist, and values are just bit patterns.)

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. What is the reason that C does not have a fixed method for casting `signed int` to `unsigned int` ?

Comment: @xfce4: It does have a fixed method for *casting* `signed int` to `unsigned int`, which I note in my answer: the result of the conversion is computed modulus one more than the maximum value of the `unsigned int`. At runtime, however, types don't exist, so there is no way that `printf` can know what the type of its arguments are. If you use `%x`, the argument's bit pattern will be interpreted as though it were an `unsigned int`, regardless of what the argument is. As it happens, that has the same effect on x86, but that has nothing to do with C.

Comment: Currentlly C does not mandate a binary format for signed integer values. Although all known implementations do use 2's-complement, the C standard allows other possibilities. That will change with C23. Nonetheless, the standard does not sanction you lying to `printf` (or any other variadic function). Because variadic functions cannot detect the "type" of their arguments (precisely because types don't exist outside of the compiler), it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the argument provided has the precise type expected by the function being called.

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like `printf("%x", a);` outputs "the value of `a`" in hexadecimal format. I was trying to display "the memory content" in hexadecimal format irrespective of the type/interpretation.

Comment: @xfce4: you cannot, in general, rely on that. If `a` is a `signed int`, it will (most likely) work, but if `a` is, for example, a `double`, anything could happen. If you want to examine C objects byte by byte, you are allowed to use `memcpy` to copy the object into an `unsigned char` array of the correct size, and then print out the unsigned chars one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The exact rules for converting between signed and unsigned types are listed in section 6.3.1.3 of the [C11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf):

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new
> type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type.
>
> *3* Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
> implementation-defined signal is raised.

As for what the above means for this code:

```
signed char a = -5;
printf("%x \n", (signed short) a); 
printf("%x \n", (unsigned short) a);
```

There are a few things going on here.

For the first `printf`, you first have a conversion from `signed char` to `signed short`.  By clause 1 above, since the value -5 can be stored in both, the value is unchanged by the cast.  Then, because this value is passed to a variadic function, it is then *promoted* to type `int`, and again by clause 1 the value is unchanged.

Then the resulting `int` value is printed with the `%x` format specifier, which is expecting an `unsigned int`.  This is technically undefined behavior for a mismatched format specifier, although most implementations will allow for implicit signed / unsigned reinterpretation.  So assuming two's complement representation, the representation of the `int` value -5 will be printed, and assuming a 32 bit `int` this will be `fffffffb`.

For the second `printf`, the conversion from `signed char` to `unsigned short` will happen according to clause 2 above since the value -5 can't be stored in a `unsigned short`.  Assuming a 16 bit short, this gives you the value 65536 - 5 = 65531.  And assuming two complement representation, this is equivalent to sign-extending the representation from `fb` to `fffb`.  This `unsigned short` value is then promoted to `int` when it is passed to `printf`, and by clause 1 the value is unchanged.  Then the `%x` format specifier prints this as `fffb`.